# Concatenate values of a property based on another property

Tags: c#, arrays, string, list, linq

I have this class

```
public enum SubStatus { active, inactive, unset}
public class SubItem
{
    public SubStatus Status { get; set; }

    public string Value { get; set; }
}
```

And the values in the class could look like this

```
List<SubItem> list = new List<SubItem>()
{
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active, Value = "1" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active, Value = "2" }, //active again, add "2" to the previous
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.inactive, Value = "1" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active, Value = "2" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset, Value = "2" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset, Value = "1" }, //unset again, add "1" to the previous
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset, Value = "1" } //unset again, add "1" to the previous
};
```

now I need to merge the string values together in case the `Status` of a item equals the `Status` of the previous item. so in this example the result should look like this

```
List <SubItem> output = new List<SubItem>()
{
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active, Value = "12" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.inactive, Value = "1" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active, Value = "2" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset, Value = "211" }
};
```

what I've tried so far does work but somehow I think this approach is wrong and there is better way with linq...

```
List<SubItem> result = new List<SubItem>();
SubItem temp = list.FirstOrDefault();
if (temp != null)
{
    foreach (SubItem item in list.Skip(1))
    {
        if (temp.Status == item.Status)
        {
            temp.Value += item.Value;
        }
        else if (temp.Status != item.Status)
        {
            result.Add(temp);
            temp = item;
        }
    }
}
result.Add(temp);
```

Answer (score 3):

Standard Linq *doesn't provide* grouping like this, but we can implement it *manually*:

```
  public static partial class EnumerableExtensions {
    public static IEnumerable<T[]> ToBatch<T>(this IEnumerable<T> source,
                                              Func<ICollection<T>, T, bool> addToBatch) {

      if (null == source)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(source));
      else if (null == addToBatch)
        throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(addToBatch));

      List<T> batch = new List<T>();

      foreach (T item in source) {
        // Shall we start a new batch?
        if (batch.Count > 0 && !addToBatch(batch, item)) {
          yield return batch.ToArray();

          batch.Clear();
        }

        batch.Add(item);
      }

      if (batch.Count > 0) // do we have a last batch?
        yield return batch.ToArray();
    }
  }
```

Now, we can use our implemenation as

```
  // Test Data
  List<SubItem> list = new List<SubItem>() {
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active,   Value = "1" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active,   Value = "2" },   
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.inactive, Value = "1" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.active,   Value = "2" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset,    Value = "2" },
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset,    Value = "1" }, 
    new SubItem() { Status = SubStatus.unset,    Value = "1" } 
  };

  ...

  List<SubItem> result = list
    .ToBatch((batch, item) => item.Status == batch.First().Status)
    .Select(batch => new SubItem() {
      Status = batch.First().Status,
      Value  = string.Concat(batch.Select(item => item.Value))
    })
    .ToList();

  // Let's have a look  
  Console.Write(string.Join(Environment.NewLine, result
    .Select(item => $"{item.Status,-8} : {item.Value}")));
```

**Outcome:**

```
active   : 12
inactive : 1
active   : 2
unset    : 211
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `Aggregate` but IMO it is not better than regular `foreach`:

```
var result = list
    .Aggregate(
        (IEnumerable<SubItem>)Array.Empty<SubItem>(), 
        (result, item) => 
            result.LastOrDefault()?.Status == item.Status
                ? result.SkipLast(1).Concat(new [] { new SubItem { Status = item.Status, Value = result.Last().Value + item.Value } })
                : result.Concat(new [] { item })
    )
    .ToList();
```

Here is other idea (using `TakeWhile`), but it is even more complicated:

```
var result2 = list
    .Select((item, index) => list
        .Take(index + 1)
        .Reverse()
        .TakeWhile(x => x.Status == item.Status)
        .Select((x, i) => Tuple.Create(x, index - i))
        .Reverse()
    )
    .GroupBy(x => x.Select(y => y.Item2).Min())
    .Select(x => x.Last())
    .Select(x => new SubItem
    {
        Status = x.First().Item1.Status,
        Value = string.Join("", x.Select(y => y.Item1.Value))
    })
    .ToList();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't do this all with standard LINQ, but you can however leverage [`GroupAdjacent`](https://morelinq.github.io/3.1/ref/api/html/Overload_MoreLinq_MoreEnumerable_GroupAdjacent.htm) from [`MoreLINQ`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/morelinq):

```
var result = list
    .GroupAdjacent(item => item.Status)
    .Select(grp => new SubItem
    {
        Status = grp.Key,
        Value = string.Concat(grp.Select(item => item.Value))
    });

foreach (var item in result)
{
    Console.WriteLine(item.ToString());
}
```

Which groups the adjacent items by `Status`, selects a new `SubItem` using [`Enumerable.Select`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.select?view=netframework-4.8), and then combines the grouped values using [`String.Concat`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.string.concat?view=netframework-4.8).

The above example outputs the following:

```
Status=active,Value=12
Status=inactive,Value=1
Status=active,Value=2
Status=unset,Value=211
```

**Note:** The above overrides the `ToString()` method of `SubItem`:

```
public override string ToString()
{
    return $"Status={Status},Value={Value}";
}
```